# iOS Persistent Notification / Quick Launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm curious if anyone can provide information on how apps like AppSwitcher use the notification center to create persistent quick-launch notifications.

I know that they are using a url to do launch apps, but what I'm looking for is how to create the notification and keep it persistent.

Answer (score 3):

If your app creates a notification and doesn't clear notifications programmatically, it will remain in Notification Center until the user clears all notifications from your app.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to come up with is calling something like a following ever so often:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

This will delete the current notification, and replace it with a new one. However, it's not really persistent, and another drawback is that the screen will turn on when the notification gets refreshed. Still searching for a better way.